# Team Error encountered while publishing the Safari extension via Xcode

Tags: xcode, safari-extension

I've created a Safari extension using Xcode, and it works fine on my local system. However, when I try to deploy the extension, I encounter an error message stating "No team found in archive." I've already added the team while setting up the extension. Could someone please assist me in identifying what I might be doing incorrectly? Below are screenshots showing my configuration and the error message I'm encountering during deployment.

Following are the configuration screeshots

[image: Setting Extension]

[image: Setting Extension]

Following is the error screeshot

[image: Error Extension]